# Scala's "This" and MapLike

Tags: scala, dictionary, this, scala-collections

Say I wanted to extend Scala's MapLike trait with a concrete implementation, IntIntMap. In order to do so, I need to implement the following methods,

```
def get(key: A): Option[B]
def iterator: Iterator[(A, B)]
def + [B1 >: B](kv: (A, B1)): This
def -(key: A): This
```

What is the `This` type?  Should my overriding method signature be,

```
override def +=(kv: (Int, Int)): IntIntMap = {
  // logic
}
```

Or just `scala.reflect.This`?  What about the class definition?  Should it be,

```
class IntIntMap(...) extends MapLike[Int,Int,This] { ... }
```

or something else entirely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should extend `MapLike[Int, Int, IntIntMap]`, and `This` becomes `IntIntMap`.

Comment: This is exactly the answer to this question, though it should be noted that if you actually want to implement a MapType you also need to extend "Map".  I don't understand the logic behind this, but it's required for the type in the +This area in MapLike's signature.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look first at [The Architecture of Scala Collections](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl.html). It shows you how to integrate you own collections.

However, you will have some trouble implementing the `+` method in you example, because it should allow to add values matching a supertype of Int and returning an appropriate `Map`. Since `This` should be a `Map[Int,Int]` you will run into trouble.

I would rather recommend to just have a type definition somewhere:

```
type MapIntInt = Map[Int,Int]
```

and eventually use implicits to bring specific methods.

Comment: I purposefully chose IntIntMap to make for a simple example.  To actually use a class like this in practice would be silly.

Comment: A great link!  It cleared up a couple other detail causing compilation errors as well.

Comment: @duckworthd: I had trouble last week implementing something like Map[A,Int] where A can change but Int is fixed. I don't think its possible via Map/Maplike. I just want to avoid you the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Not a reserved word, not the name of some class, but the third type parameter in MapLike. 
Type declaration is `MapLike[K, +V, +This <: MapLike[K, V, This]`. It could be called any other way. Most of the time, the This should be the actual implementor class, hence the name. in your case

```
class IntIntMap extends MapLike [Int, Int, IntIntMap].
```

Without that parameter, `+` result type would have be declared MapLike, not IntIntMap. On `+`, that would not be a problem, because you have to define it, and doing that you can change the result type. But methods that you don't need to redefine and which are implemented using `+` (such as the `++` would still return MapLike.